# How can I update a file upload in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel

I've built something that I would expect to work. It should upload the file and replace the 'attachment' entry for the record with the new file's path. Here is the method:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $article = Article::find($id);
    $article->username = Session::get('username');
    $article->body = Input::get('body');
    $article->title = Input::get('title');
    if(Input::hasFile('attachment'))
    {
        $file = Input::file('attachment');
        $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file = $file->move(public_path() . '/documents/articles/', $name);
        $article->attachment = $name;;
    }
    $article->save();//Commit this edit to the database
    return Redirect::route('articles.index');
}
```

And the form:

```
<div class="form-general">
    {{ Form::model($article, array('route' => array('articles.update', $article->id, 'files' => true), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
    <div>
        {{ Form::label('title', 'Title:') }}
        {{ Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control' )) }}
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        @if(! empty($article->attachment))
        {{ Form::label('attachment', 'Attachment:') }} <br />
        <div class="attachment-replace" style="display:none;">

        {{ Form::file('attachment', null, array('class' => 'form-control' )) }}

        </div>
        <a class="current-attachment" href="/documents/articles/{{ $article->attachment }}">{{ $article->attachment }}</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="current-attachment"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle remove-attachment"></span></a>
        @else
        {{ Form::label('attachment', 'Attachment:') }}
        {{ Form::file('attachment', null, array('class' => 'form-control' )) }}
        @endif
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        {{ Form::label('body', 'Body:') }}
        {{ Form::textarea('body', null, array('class' => 'form-control' )) }}
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>{{ Form::submit('Edit Post', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}</div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

Currently, nothing happens. The method gets executed and the other fields update fine, but the attachment does not. It seems that the File input "attachment" never even gets set. How can I properly update a file path and upload its replacement document at once?

Comment: Can you make sure it gets into the `hasFile` if? Just add `dd('test')` in there..

Comment: It doesn't seem to. I guess that means it's never seeing that a file has been attached, but I'm still not sure as to why that might happen. I have 'files' set to true, and the input loads and allows the selection of a file.

Comment: Ok. I'm just grasping at straws now but maybe there's a problem because you're using `Form::model`. `$article->attachment` is a path and the field with the name attachment is a file upload. Try renaming the file upload to something else.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your suggestion. What are you suggesting I rename? $article->attachment refers to the field with the name attachment.

Comment: Yes I know, and I wonder if that's the problem. So rename `Form::file('attachment')` to `Form::file('attachmentInput')` and do the same for `Input::hasFile` and `Input::file` but keep `$article->attachment` the way it is.
This is just for testing, I know its kind of against the concept behind the form model...

Comment: No luck. Just as before, it seems the file never makes it into the input array nor file array, the file never gets uploaded, and the path does not get updated in the database.

Comment: Hmmm.. Is the generated html (source of the page in your browser) ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `files` parameter is part of the wrong array. You have this line, which opens your form :

`{{ Form::model($article, array('route' => array('articles.update', $article->id, 'files' => true), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}`

If you look closely, you will find that the `files => true` option is part of your `route` array, however it should be outside of it. Like so :

`{{ Form::model($article, array('route' => array('articles.update', $article->id), 'files' => true, 'method' => 'PUT')) }}`

As they say, the devil is in the details ;)

Comment: Thank you, sir. I appreciate this. I didn't realize I had it nested in the route's array. I'll have to be more careful in the future.